# Проверка корректности html тегов

Tags: php

Добрый день! Мне нужно Написать функцию, которая на входе принимает массив из открывающихся или закрывающихся тегов,  а возвращает результат проверки корректности. Вот что у меня сделано, но работает неправильно. Подскажите, в чем проблема или нужно мне другой алгоритм решения? Спасибо.

```
   (например “<a>”, “</td>” )

$корректная_структура = ['<a>', '<div>', '</div>', '</a>', '<span>', '</span>'];
$некорректная_структура = ['<a>', '<div>', '</a>', '<p>' , '</tr>'];

function validate_html_tags($html_tags) {

$tags = htmlspecialchars(implode("", $html_tags));
$html_doc="<!DOCTYPE html>" . "<html><body>" . $tags . "</body></html>";    
// $html_doc="<!DOCTYPE html>" . $tags . ;    
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html_doc);
$dom->saveHTML();

if ($dom->validate()) {
    echo "This document is valid!\n";
} else {
    echo "This document is invalid!\n";
}

return $tags;
```

}

```
Вот ошибки: 

Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): No declaration for element html in 
Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): No declaration for element body in 
This document is invalid! string(67) "<a><div></div></a><span></span>"
```

Comment: Подскажите, в чем проблема? Функция на входе принимает оба массив, и все таки ожидаемый результат не получаю.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а просто сделать массив счетчиков тегов и делать +1 если открылся и -1 если закрылся, а потом суммировать значения и проверять сумму на 0 уже не модно?

Comment: @wirtwelt не модно, так как уже давно есть встроенные классы и проверки для подобных вещей

Comment: @Capfer кроме прочего, вам не следует делать `htmlspecialchars`, это сводит на нет всю вашу идею валидации, выведите `$html_doc`, посмотрите что вы валидируете. Про необходимость DTD написал в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание, что функция [DOMDocument::validate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php) работает не так, как вы ожидаете. Она не валидирует HTML, но валидирует XML. Причём делает это используя схему ([DTD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTD)). В XML документе обычно присутствует ссылка на схему, которой он соответствует.

Старые версии HTML тоже содержали такие ссылки в DOCTYPE (например `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`), если открыть http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd, то можно увидеть описание формата HTML4! Именно по этому формату и производится валидация.

HTML5 вы так валидировать не сможете (из википедии: "Синтаксис HTML5 больше не базируется на SGML, несмотря на подобие его разметки."), так как для него нет DTD-схемы. Да вам это и не нужно (вы можете использовать DOCTYPE HTML4, но валидатор будет скачивать схему при каждом запуске). Вы можете либо самостоятельно посчитать, что теги открываются и закрываются правильно или [поискать готовое решение](https://packagist.org/?query=html%20validate).

Answer (score -1):

```
Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): No declaration for element html in 
Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): No declaration for element body in
```

Первые 2 ошибки возникли из-за того, что Вы использовали метод saveHtml для неправильной структуры домдокумента без валидации.

3 сообщение - оповещение о том, что документ не прошел валидацию.

Вы пропустили `<head>` и класс DOMDocument ругается на некорректный документ.

Замените

`$html_doc="<!DOCTYPE html>" . "<html><body>" . $tags . "</body></html>";`

На

`$html_doc="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>" . $tags . "</body></html>";`

И `$dom->saveHTML();` добавьте после успешной валидации

И раз уж задача состоит в `возвращает результат проверки корректности` то возвращать нужно не $tag, а true или false в зависимости от результатов. Вот переделанный вариант функции

```
function validate_html_tags($html_tags) {

$tags = htmlspecialchars(implode("", $html_tags));
$html_doc="<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><html><body>" . $tags . "</body></html>";      
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html_doc);

if ($dom->validate()) {
    echo "This document is valid!\n";
    $dom->saveHTML(); // хотя зачем тут это
    return true;
} 

echo "This document is invalid!\n";

return false;   
}
```

Comment: Peresada, спасибо за корректирование, но Я такое изменение уже сделал и все таки не работает. $dom->validate() возврвщает warnings.